# How to implement a click handler with CardService?

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on, google-workspace-add-ons

I need to click a select/deselect all checkboxes using the `CardService`.

How do I implement an `onclick` handler function?

I have tried with:

```
function handlerOfButtonClick(e) {
    var selectAll = CardService.newSelectionInput()
        .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX)
        .setFieldName("select_all")
        .addItem("Select all", "selectAll", false).setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
            .setFunctionName("handleSelectAll"));

    var checkboxGroup = CardService.newSelectionInput()
        .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX)
        .setTitle("A group of checkboxes. Multiple selections are allowed.")
        .setFieldName("checkbox_field")
        .addItem("checkbox one title", "checkbox_one_value", false)
        .addItem("checkbox two title", "checkbox_two_value", true)
        .addItem("checkbox three title", "checkbox_three_value", true);

    var section = CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(selectAll).addWidget(checkboxGroup)
    var card = CardService.newCardBuilder().addSection(section);
    var navigation = CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(card.build());
    var actionResponse = CardService.newActionResponseBuilder().setNavigation(navigation);
    return actionResponse.build();
}

function handleSelectAll(e) {
    //????? 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [updateCard(card)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/navigation#updatecardcard)

This allows you to replace the card you built with a version where all check boxes are checked (that is se to `true`).

Sample:

```js
function handleSelectAll(e) {
    
    var checkboxGroup = CardService.newSelectionInput()
        .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX)
        .setTitle("A group of checkboxes. Multiple selections are allowed.")
        .setFieldName("checkbox_field")
        .addItem("checkbox one title", "checkbox_one_value", true)
        .addItem("checkbox two title", "checkbox_two_value", true)
        .addItem("checkbox three title", "checkbox_three_value", true);

    var section = CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(selectAll).addWidget(checkboxGroup)
    var card = CardService.newCardBuilder().addSection(section);

    return CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(card.build());
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of checking the checks because my checkbox es are many and dynamic causing a lot of time...

Comment: Maybe you can add to the checkboxes an `setOnChangeAction()` that would store the state of the checkbox in [Script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)?

Comment: For setting script properties? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036894/trigger-an-alert-at-a-specific-time-on-google-script/62127902#62127902) is a sample.

Comment: If I do this updateCard, the base form values will not be taken to newly spawned card. How do I handle it?

Comment: It is hard to comprehend the scope of your project, but if you cannot pass the necessary values parameters to `handleSelectAll()`, you can store and retrieve the values the script properties as mentioned above.

Comment: I have emailed you the script